# Counting total rows on a datagrid

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to count all the rows on a datagrid after it has been populated from my DB. I have searched online on how to do this but nothing seems to work.

here is how I grab my data

```
    test.SelectCommand = Ssql
    test.SelectParameters.Clear()
    test.DataBind()
```

where test is my datasource it gets thrown into. Any help is appreciated TY!

Answer (score 3):

My code for this thing is:
`TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount` 
it display the number of row populated with some data.

Answer (score 1):

Gets or sets number of rows displayed.

`test.RowCount`

Can also use.

`test.Rows.Count`

Comment: it errors out with, RowCount' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'?

Comment: Yeah, sorry was thinking `test` was your `DataGridView` for some reason.